# How to return two dicts instead of returning set?

Tags: python

```
def foo():
    dict_1 = dict()
    dict_2 = dict()

    return dict_1, dict_2

print(foo())
```

result: `({}, {})`

But I need `{}, {}`

How to do it?

I am trying to return data from function but getting:

See:

```
[{
        'root': {
            'id': '17958765',

        }
    }, ({
        'lots': [{
                'purchaseNumber': '0873500000818004164'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        'PurchaseObjects': [{
            {
                'OKPD2_code': '123',
                'OKPD2_name': 'ffff'
            }
        ]
    })]
```

Comment: `{}, {}` is `({}, {})`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `print(*foo())` use this

Comment: this now returns a _list_ of a _dict_ and a _tuple_ containing two _dict_ ... and the inner dicts have a value that contains a 1-element list containing another dict...

Comment: What code gave you the list you gave with 'See:'? Definitely not the return value of your `foo()`.

Comment: How to get two dict without tuple?

Comment: You can not return _two_ values from a function - you can only ever return one. This returned element can be a container - f.e. a tuple or a list that contains other things. (*) simplified - not going into yield and generators

Answer (score 0):

Those are the same thing, only `({}, {})` is printed in a non-ambiguous way.

The function is returning a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (more closely 2-tuple), not a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) as your title says.

Answer (score 0):

`foo()` will give you a 2-tuple of two dictionaries. Fetch the return value, and index or unpack the tuple to get individual access to your two dictionaries.

```py
def foo():
    dict_1 = dict()
    dict_2 = dict()

    return dict_1, dict_2

# Do either one of the following (indexing or unpacking)

# Indexing a tuple
return_value = foo()
dict_1 = return_value[0]
dict_2 = return_value[1]

# Unpacking a tuple
dict_1, dict_2 = foo()
```

In the example you gave, unpacking is apparently the better way to go, but in some cases you might want to keep the returned tuple and access its elements later with indexing.